# Lodash _.get undefined when using Lodash without Node?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to create a simple static web page to mess around with some Lodash functions like `_.get()`. Their docs only specify how to set the `_` variable via Node `require()` syntax. I don't want Node involved for a simple static page.

Putting `lodash.core.min.js` in a `<script>` tag isn't allowing me to test `_.get()`. Is it possible to do this without Node?

**UPDATE (solved)**

`lodash.core` does not contain the `get()` function. (per [github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Build-Differences](http://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Build-Differences.))

Using `lodash.min.js` lets me do what I want. `lodash.core.min.js` does not.

Comment: It should be. You can also dynamically load it through `require.js`.

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem (because this works: https://jsbin.com/sopigik/edit?html,js,console).

Comment: `lodash.min.js` and `lodash.js` attached `_` to the window. [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ar1vtubb/3/). This likely an issue with `lodash.core` in the browser as it's not packaged as UMD or similar.

Comment: Ah yup, it was lodash.js vs lodash.core.js. Thanks everyone

Comment: lodash.core.js also works, as can be seen in my second link. An example which triggers the error would really help...

Comment: And as you can simply see in my link lodash.core.min.js adds `_` to the global scope. The error "simply" is, that the core build doesn't has the `.get()` method: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Build-Differences.

Comment: @Andreas I'm not sure why you are using such an aggressive tone. I've updated my question to reflect your findings.

Comment: No aggression from me, but the original question/problem was not existent/possible and you refused to add an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which would have shown the real problem. Also the correct error message would have help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [_.noConflict()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#noConflict)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script>
_u = _.noConflict(); 
  users = [
  { user: 'barney', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 40, active: false },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true}
];

result = _u.filter(users, function(o) { return o.active; });
console.log(result);
</script>
```

Comment: It's actually because I was using `lodash.core.min.js` instead of `lodash.min.js`! Thanks though

Answer (score -1):

In https://codepen.io you can simply add lodash as dependency from the quick add. It is a great way to test it:
[image: codepen screenshot]

Also you can use this already prepared pen: [test lodash](https://codepen.io/travist/full/jrBjBz)

```
var users = [
  { user: 'barney', age: 36, active: true },
  { user: 'fred',  age: 40, active: false },
  { user: 'travis', age: 37, active: true}
];

result = _.filter(users, function(o) { return o.active; });
```